# Excel VBA current range cell selection issue

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

i have this code below in which i select range and then to offset to get the handle of one cell down of base_red range. The moment the next line of pastespecial is run it copies the data to range "mon" but also the cursor selection moves to "mon" range.

I don't want the selection to remain at the old place only and not able to figure out how to stop the selection at old place only.
I require this because i have to do some more offset and paste the values to new locations.

```
If count1 = 1 Then
        ws.Range("base_red").Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
    ActiveCell.Copy

    ws.Range("mon").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: A bit confused as to your question, but normally best practice is to [avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: you can potentially do it in one line `ws.Range("mon").value = ws.Range("base_red").Offset(1, 0).value`

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to use select.  The following code copies one range to another.  I implied from  your example that you want to ensure you only copy and paste a single cell.  If that is not the case, remove both instances of ".Cells(1,1)" from the code.

```
Public Sub Temp()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    count1 = 1
    If count1 = 1 Then
        ws.Range("mon").Cells(1, 1) = ws.Range("base_red").Offset(1, 0).Cells(1, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is another method which makes the fewest changes to your code.

```
Public Sub Temp()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    count1 = 1
    If count1 = 1 Then
        ws.Range("base_red").Select
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Copy

    ' save the location of the active cell to rng.
    Set rng = ActiveCell
    
    ws.Range("mon").PasteSpecial
    ' return to the previous active cell
    rng.Select

End Sub
```